# How can be used multiple filter in the numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to filter some data out from an array

```
 data = data[data['RotSpeed'] <= ROTOR_SPEED ]
 data = data[data['HorWindV'] <= WIND_SPEED ]
```

I am wondering if this can be optimized by combining the two filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can intersect two filters with the `&` operator:

```py
data = data[(data['RotSpeed'] <= ROTOR_SPEED) & (data['HorWindV'] <= WIND_SPEED)]
```

Or union two conditions with the `|` operator:

```py
data = data[(data['RotSpeed'] <= ROTOR_SPEED) | (data['HorWindV'] <= WIND_SPEED)]
```

**make sure to use parentheses around the field and the filter placed for it**

It is unlikely to be much of an optimization though.

Comment: I tried this solution but I forgot the brackets. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to know, and it's data-dependent anyway.  This way you have to do both comparisons for all elements, whereas in the OP's original approach, if the first cull eliminated 99% of the data the second would be very fast.